# List Child Categorie and hide the parent

Tags: categories, list

Greetings!

I'm trying to list child categories in a sidebar, but also hide the parent cat.

I'm using this at the moment:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=5'); ?>
```

This has a unfortunate effect of displaying 'Categories' above the list. Is there any way to get rid of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `&title_li=` to your code like so to remove the word "Categories":

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=5&title_li='); ?>
```

More information on categories can be found in the codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: Hat's off to You, Madam. This did the trick. BTW, I looked at the codex but couldn't exactly that.